# Entitiy Framework Complex Types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to nest EF compex types and use in a domain entity ?

If it is possible what kind of configuration is necesary for complex type parent and complex type child ?

```
ComplexType Parent
{
 public ComplexTypeChild { get; set;}
 //other properties
}

ComplexTypeChild
{
 public string Name{ get; set;}
 //other properties
}

DomainEntity
{
 public ParentComplexType {get; private set; }
 //other properties and method
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Here is the configuration you need to add in the OnModelCreating event.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.ComplexType<ComplexType>();
    mb.ComplexType<ComplexTypeChild>();
}
```

Comment: @JohnatanMagnan I know this is a stupid question but I have encounterd a problem during EF POCOs design, and since your anwser was helpful I would like to ask you the question. Should I make EF POCOS just with a pramametrless constructor, or include constructors defined in the domain class? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, both answer are good for me, I'm not sure what's the best practices for this. I believe it's depend how you will use your domain class. By example, a customer class may have a complex type "CustomerInfo" with already initialized default value (so in the domain class constructors) but not doing it and forcing to create a new CustomerInfo make sense also.